# Looking for audio amplifier circuit using 2SC1050 transistor

Tags: amplifier, audio

Will I be able to find any audio amplifier diagrams using 2SC1050 transistor? I've looked and looked, but can't find any. I mainly want to see what audio power out etc. so I can get an understanding of the datasheet.

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question in your "question". Or at least, the question you've asked: "Will I be able to find any audio amplifier diagrams using 2SC1050 transistor", is really only answerable by you and depends mostly on where and how you search.

Comment: You 2SC1050 is OK to make an powerful 40W audio amp: https://i.imgur.com/dtLY2Nn.jpeg. But you may like to start with smaller one, say 1W. I would recommend to start off with the following newbie tutorial: "Amplifiers Summary - Electronics Tutorials":
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amp_8.html. You may like to start with "Class A" amplifiers. Cheers.

Comment: There are many good newbie tutorials on audio amp.  Here is an example:
Transistor Amplifier - Circuits Today
https://www.circuitstoday.com/transistor-amplifier. Have a great project. Cheers.

Comment: Lazy me skipped Class A, B, C and jump start at digital Class D power amp:  
(1) https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32828586240.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.49.3c7422fdynOucR&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_319_5735015_317_5734915_10696_10084_453_10924_454_10083_10618_10920_10921_10307_10922_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_5735215_321_322_10103_5735115,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe-7&algo_pvid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe
(2) https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=224976&start=25#p1396404. Cheers.

Comment: It is not just because of laziness. DIY Class A, B amplifiers using power transistors use old analog knowledge and skills which are not useful at all in modern digital world. If you can use IC, ASIC,MPU, SBC, there is no reason to go back using transistors. However, ages ago I did use vacuum tubes to DIY power audio amp: https://www.amazon.com/Vacuum-Tube-Amplifier/s?k=Vacuum+Tube+Amplifier and I always think vacuum tube power amp has the most natural sound, transistor power amp (using 2N3055 NPN BJT) etc sound is not natural, and digital Class D amp is rubbish, harmful to human ears!

Comment: The high voltage, low current transistor is not used in audio power amplifiers. 30W into an 8 ohm speaker has a peak current of 2.7A but the Oriental transistor has a maximum allowed current of only 1A.

Comment: Vacuum tube amplifiers use an output transformer that muffles high audio frequencies. The tubes produce even-order harmonic distortion that is not harsh but is "musical".  A 2N3055 transistor is almost as old as tubes. Modern class-D anplifiers sound perfect and produce little heating.

Comment: @Audioguru, I agree. For 2SC1050, you need to use a 32 Ohm speaker to get 30W.  But nowadays everybody is using 4 Ohm or 8 Ohm speakers. That is why I don't suggest the OP to play with old school transistors. You can't even find hardware to match them, not to mention learning old knowledge and skills you cannot apply.

Comment: @Audioguru, I was a bit joking when I said digital power amp damages human ears, though I am always a huge fan of those-were-the-days McIntosh:) 
(1) Why Tubes Sound Better - kenrockwell
https://www.kenrockwell.com/audio/why-tubes-sound-better.htm. Cheers.

Comment: @Audioguru, Ah yes, your comment "Vacuum tube amplifiers use an output transformer that muffles high audio frequencies" reminds me of the use of the similar coupling capacitor. So I was a bit surprised but sad that these days digital power amp modules, eg PAM8610, ***no longer need to use any coupling capacitors, just direct connect the speaker***. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you everyone for supplying me with all those answers. I used to make RF  antenna for and old amateur radio enthusiast here in NZ when his eyesight was failing. He gave me a lot of transistors etc. Im slowly working out the numbers on them as bit worn  and find out there uses

Comment: Like all modern amplifier ICs, the PAM8610 uses bridging (two amplifiers, one for each speaker wire) then each speaker wire is driven with opposite phase for almost 4 times the output power and no DC offset. Then no series output coupling capacitor is needed that cuts low frequencies.

Comment: @Mike Hall, Ah, now I see why you are playing with the very old 2SC1050. As I said earlier, you can just use the tutorials and schematics for similar transistor like 2N3055. BTW, you reminded me that in my days, I used to go to the corner newspaper stands every week to get magazines like "Electronics Weekly" to learn how to build amplifiers, transistor radios,  and power supplies etc. You might like to read the article in Reference (1) of my answer to learn more about those were the days. Cheers.

Comment: I've only ever seen them used in a high voltage power supply, and lo, Google just turned up this: http://www.elde.cz/datasht/2SC1050.pdf

In audio amps, the 2SC1080 (with its complementary cousin 2SA680) was more common, I think.

Answer (score 2):

***Part 1 - Use 2N3055 to learn audio amplifier***

***Update 2020sep24hkt14:47***

How nice to see @ocrdu updating our crowded answer with the following critical jigsaw puzzle piece!

[image: 2SC1050 audio amplifier]

---

*Update and Errata 2020sep24hkt1322* - The above title before this update had a typo - 2N3005 SCR should read 2N3005 NPN transistor.  Many thanks to @Andrew Morton for pointing out my severe careless mistake.

---

2SC1050 is not that popular, therefore you find it difficult to google things for it.

Instead you may like to try 2N3055, which can do what 2SC1050 can, and is perhaps 100 times more popular, so you can find tons of tutorials on it.

The following is an example of a couple of YouTube tutorials to get you started.

(1) [DIY Audio Amplifier with 2N3055 Transistor - cbz 2019nov23](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UDR7_f6ovM)

---

***Part 2 Small Power audio amplifiers***

2SC2050 or 2N3055 are for big power audio amp.  For smaller power, you might like to consider the following.

(a) [DIY PAM8610 Digital HiFi Power Amplifier Board 15W + 15W Small Power Mini Audio Amp Kit DC12V - US$8](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32828586240.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.49.3c7422fdynOucR&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10065_10068_319_5735015_317_5734915_10696_10084_453_10924_454_10083_10618_10920_10921_10307_10922_537_536_10059_10884_10887_100031_5735215_321_322_10103_5735115,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe-7&algo_pvid=313c57d7-aac8-47a4-a578-88810d9ecbfe)

(b) [LM386 Low Voltage Audio Power Amplifier - TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf)

---

***References***

(1) [Whatever Happened To The Electronics Hobbyist?](https://www.electronicdesign.com/archive/article/21752153/whatever-happened-to-the-electronics-hobbyist)

(2) [eevBLAB #2 - Are Electronics Hobbyists Useless? (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iXFhKUa1BU)

(3) [EEVblog #874 - World's Oldest Electronics Hobbyist! (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cU7zCx_liM)

(4) [The Decline of Hobby Electronics? (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLnolhyT5SI)

(5) [An Electronics Workspace for a Design Engineer - elektormagazine](https://www.elektormagazine.com/news/workspace-design-engineer)

(6) [The 10 Best Raspberry Pi Stores Available in the Market](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-raspberry-pi-stores-available-in-the-market/)

(7) [Inside a 12W LED module (12:26 Schematic) - BigClive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhlM2sPU_Z0&t=227s)

(8) [2SC1050 Based Power Amplifier](http://www.elde.cz/datasht/2SC1050.pdf)

(9) [JohnAudioTech Videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/JohnAudioTech/videos)

---

Comment: Why are so many You Tube electronics videos from India, use antique parts and show no schematic? I guess You Tube pays them each time a viewer sees an ad.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of those Youtube videos on antique parts without showing schematic. Perhaps you can one or two links so I can watch and then comment. By the way, I am a huge fan of the EEVblog, ranked in the following list: 10 Electronics Youtube Channels for Electrical & Electronic Engineers - 2020sep22
https://blog.feedspot.com/electronics_youtube_channels/

Comment: @Audioguru, your complaint about videos showing no schematics reminds me of BigClive, also ranked Top 10 EE Youtube Videos. The good things about Big Clives are that: (1)  His stuff is usually very up to date, often explaining thing in details, showing schematics when necessary, and often explain how to read datasheets. When I started playing with power electronics some years ago, I learnt quite a lot from his educational and at the same time entertaining videos. Here is an example: Inside a 12W LED module (12:26 Schematic) - BigClive
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhlM2sPU_Z0&t=227s.

Comment: I am chatting and at the same time appending references of the chatted stuff in the reference list. This way, future readers need not to follow our chats, and read the references to learn the prerequisites in understanding the problem. I won't answer the OP's specific question of where to search the 2SC050 schematic, but my suggestion that 2N3055 is a good replacement and my reference list helps the OP and future readers to learn the prerequisites to perhaps find the answer himself. This morning I included the Elektor magazine which is a good source for both EE hobbyists newbies and oldies.